# Getting the path of a value in JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have a JSON file like so (char_table.json):

```
{
  "char_285_medic2": {
    "name": "Lancet-2",
    "description": "Restores the HP of allies and ignores the Deployment Limit, but has a long Redeployment Time",
    "canUseGeneralPotentialItem": false,
    "canUseActivityPotentialItem": false
   },
"char_291_aglina": {
    "name": "Angelina",
    "description": "Deals Arts damage and Slows the target for a short time",
    "canUseGeneralPotentialItem": true,
    "canUseActivityPotentialItem": false
   },
"char_2013_cerber": {
    "name": "Ceobe",
    "description": "Deals Arts damage",
    "canUseGeneralPotentialItem": true,
    "canUseActivityPotentialItem": false,
   },
   ...
}
```

I currently only have the "name" varible, and I want to find the path of the object containing that exact "name" (example: `name = "Angelina"` would return `char_table.char_291_aglina` | `name = "Ceobe"` would return `char_table.char_2013_cerber`). How can I exactly do that using javascript?

Comment: Why do you need this information? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: @Andy I need this to optimize my web db, since I cant just make a list of all the names and then search for every single of it, it would take a lot of time

Comment: Why did you un-accept? The solution isn't working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to get an array of keys from the `char_table` object, and then the [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to search for a key that corresponds to a character with the specified name. If a matching key is found, it is returned; otherwise, it returns `null`.

```js
function findCharacterKeyByName(char_table, name) {
    return Object.keys(char_table).find((key) => char_table[key].name === name) || null;
}

const char_table = {
    char_291_aglina: {
        name: "Angelina",
        description: "Deals Arts damage",
        canUseGeneralPotentialItem: true,
        canUseActivityPotentialItem: false,
    },
    char_2013_cerber: {
        name: "Ceobe",
        description: "Deals Arts damage",
        canUseGeneralPotentialItem: true,
        canUseActivityPotentialItem: false,
    },
};

const nameToFind = "Angelina";
const characterKeyFound = findCharacterKeyByName(char_table, nameToFind);

if (characterKeyFound) {
    console.log("Character Found: " + characterKeyFound);
} else {
    console.log("Character Not Found!");
}
```

Comment: What's the reason to downvote this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive re-usable function

1. Read the json file from a path and convert into js object

```
const fs = require('fs')

const readJSONFromFile = filePath => {
  try {
    const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
    return JSON.parse(jsonData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error reading JSON file: ${error.message}`);
    return null;
  }
}
```

2. Find the node by property name and the value of that property using recursion function

```
const findObjectNodeByPropertyAndValue = (obj, targetProperty, targetValue, currentPath = '') => {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      const newPath = currentPath ? `${currentPath}.${key}` : key;
      if (obj[key][targetProperty] === targetValue) {
        return newPath;
      } else {
        const result = findObjectNodeByPropertyAndValue(obj[key], targetProperty, targetValue, newPath);
        if (result) {
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
const filePath = '<YOUR-JSON-PATH>.json'
const charData = readJSONFromFile(filePath);
if(charData) {
  const node = `${filePath.split(".json")[0]}.${findObjectNodeByPropertyAndValue(charData, 'name', 'Angelina')}`;
  console.log(node)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const char_table = require("./char_table.json");

function getKeyFromName(askedName) {
  for ([key, value] of Object.entries(char_table)) {
    if (value.name.includes(askedName)) return key;
  }
}
console.log("result", getKeyFromName("Ceobe")); // char_2013_cerber
```